# How to access reactjs usestate value in global scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have the following reactJS code -

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const getinterviewerDetails= async ()=>{
      const data1 = await axios.get("http://localhost:8083/api/GetProduct")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("role is "+response.data[0].role)
        setinterviewerDetails(response.data)
        var cars = response.data,
        result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.role] = r[a.role] || [];
            r[a.role].push(a);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
        console.log("result is : ",result);
        console.log(interviewerDetails)
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
    setinterviewerDetails(data1);
    };  
  getinterviewerDetails();
  },[])
```

From which I need to get the result value in the global scope, out of a `useEffect` function. I tried doing so just by declaring the variable from outside of the function scope and then initializing it from with `useEffect` scope. But, it was giving value as undefined. How can I get it done? I just need to access result value from global scope.

Comment: You can use a global scrope manager like Redux. Or simply use localStorage.

Comment: React doesn't use "global" scopes. Your question needs a lot more context and clarity. Are you really just wanting to update the `interviewerDetails` state value with the computed `result` value in the Promise chain? If not, then please update your question to include all relevant code and be more explicit with that you are trying to do with the `result` variable/value. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: why are you calling `setinterviewerDetails` in two different places? and what is - `var cars = response.data, result = cars.reduce(...` ? - that is not valid syntax

Answer (score -1):

I think one way is to create context (https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) and put your variable inside of it.

Other way is to declare your variable by useState in parent component and pass setState function to child component